# how to detect mosaic region from image

Tags: mosaic

such as this image, which has mosaic blocks of different sizes
[cat with mosaic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjoy.jpg)

I would like to know how to detect such mosaic images through traditional or deep learning methods
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar rep on Github.